# Auto pilot mode of application

Tags: c++, linux, scripting

Hey Guys I am working on Gateway Simulator.
here gateway simulator is connected with the camera.gateway respond when user sends command. 
command can be like streaming video or status of the sensor associated battery information etc.There is data center also which will forward the user request to gateway.

There some information which gateway also send to the user or data center with out any request from the user or data center.like battery status down,sensor remove etc etc.

Since this simulator will be used by the developer/QA team  to simulate the gateway.they want it it to run in auto pilot mode/pre-scripted instructions mode as well.

I wanted some input from you guys o this.I wanted to know some the widely used approach to address this issue.
any link/suggestion  would be fine.This gateway simulator needs to be written ic++ for both linux and windows paltform.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on how (network, console, GUI, ...) the user is sending commands. If it's network or console, writing a script that will feed the command should not be too hard in any language, but there is a tool called [expect](http://expect.nist.gov/), built on top of [tcl](http://www.tcl.tk), that's specifically designed for this task. Alternatively if you know perl or python and don't want to learn tcl, you can use the [perl Expect module](http://search.cpan.org/~rgiersig/Expect/Expect.pod) or [python pexpect package](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pexpect/2.4) ([windows version](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/winpexpect/1.5)).

If the commands are given through a GUI, there is some tooling to automate even that in [LDTP](http://ldtp.freedesktop.org/wiki/). It should work with Gtk+ GUI and I am not sure how far it is with Qt (or whether KDE has something similar).